# How to open Windows 8 metro screen after installing Classic Start Menu?

Tags: windows-8.1

I want to uninstall built-in Skype app in Windows 8.1 as guided here.

The problem is I have no access to the [`metro screen`](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=windows%208.1%20metro%20screen&newwindow=1&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=iFfsU8aRGMXp8AW934CIBQ&ved=0CBkQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=713) of Windows 8.1 after I installed Classic Start Menu.

How can I open Windows 8 metro screen after installing [Classic Start Menu](http://www.classicshell.net/)?

Comment: Press the Windows button :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky And it will bring up classic menu dude ^^ That's what `Classic Start Menu` is for!

Answer (score 1):

well depending of the software, you can `right click` on the windows logo and in the pop-up window choose `options` or `configuration` and then you can check where you can enable the Metro UI Start

i'm using Stardock's Start8, which has the `Metro UI Start` as one of the 'pinned' icons in the Start Menu, and if your keyboard comes with right and left windows key, the left one Starts the Metro UI Menu, and the right one starts the Classic Menu

Comment: Thanks diras2010. Your hints give me the answer for `Classic Start Menu`. By the way, please have Start8 to get virus-scanned with virustotal.com - I once scan and virus detected

Comment: well, i'm using a very good firewall that asks me every time that an unknown / not-listed application tries to receive / sent info and the AV doesn't have jumped on me with that software

Comment: Fine by me as you are confident with your firewall then

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to "drag down" your desktop by grabbing it on the top. You should see the mouse cursor transforming into a hand when attempting this.

Next, drag your desktop to either side of your screen. It should be placed into some sort of sidebar.

Then, just click the large blank area next to this sidebar, and the metro screen of Windows 8 should appear...

Answer (score 0):

`Shift-Click` on the start button.

[image]

[image]